# Find location of numbers in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. Array A and Array B. Now I need to get where in array B is sequence from array A located. I need to get location of last number and I don't know how.

```
A[4]={6,3,3,2};

B[10][18]={
{5,3,6,5,6,1,6,1,4,4,5,4,4,6,3,3,1,3},
{6,2,3,6,3,3,2,4,3,1,5,5,3,4,4,1,6,5},
{6,4,3,1,6,2,2,5,3,4,3,2,6,4,5,5,1,4},
{5,3,5,6,6,4,3,2,6,5,1,2,5,6,5,2,3,1},
{1,2,5,2,6,3,1,5,4,6,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3},
{4,1,4,2,3,2,3,6,4,1,6,2,3,4,4,1,1,4},
{5,3,3,2,6,2,5,2,3,1,2,6,5,1,6,4,1,3},
{4,5,2,1,2,5,2,6,4,3,3,2,3,3,3,1,5,1},
{1,3,5,5,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,5},
{4,5,2,4,2,3,4,2,5,6,5,2,6,3,5,4,5,2}
};
```

For example: Sequence 6,3,3,2 start in second row and in forth column and ends in seventh column. I need to get location of number 2. My result should be:
Row = 2,
Column= 7

Sequence isn't always in row. It can be in column to. For example:
3,2,4,3 and I ned to know location of number 4.

I know how to search one number in one dimensional array but in this case I don't have solution.

Language is C.

Comment: what if the sequence is `3, 1, 3, 6, 2`, which are the last 3 numbers in the first row and the first 2 numbers in the second row?

Comment: if the answer of the question i just asked is `row=2, col=2`, then i recommend you an algorithm which is a just fit to your problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: This situation can't happen. But thanks for link. It may be useful anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare blocks using `memcmp`:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { /* For each row */ 
    for (j = 0; j < cols - size; j++) { /* For each col until cols - 4 */
        if (memcmp(A, &B[i][j], sizeof(A)) == 0) { /* Compare entire block */
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A[4] = {6,3,3,2};
    int B[10][18] = {
        {5,3,6,5,6,1,6,1,4,4,5,4,4,6,3,3,1,3},
        {6,2,3,6,3,3,2,4,3,1,5,5,3,4,4,1,6,5},
        {6,4,3,1,6,2,2,5,3,4,3,2,6,4,5,5,1,4},
        {5,3,5,6,6,4,3,2,6,5,1,2,5,6,5,2,3,1},
        {1,2,5,2,6,3,1,5,4,6,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3},
        {4,1,4,2,3,2,3,6,4,1,6,2,3,4,4,1,1,4},
        {5,3,3,2,6,2,5,2,3,1,2,6,5,1,6,4,1,3},
        {4,5,2,1,2,5,2,6,4,3,3,2,3,3,3,1,5,1},
        {1,3,5,5,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,5},
        {4,5,2,4,2,3,4,2,5,6,5,2,6,3,5,4,5,2}
    };
    size_t i, j, size, rows, cols;
    int founded = 0;

    size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);    
    rows = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
    cols = sizeof(B[0]) / sizeof(B[0][0]);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols - size; j++) {
            if (memcmp(A, &B[i][j], sizeof(A)) == 0) {
                founded = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (founded) break;
    }
    if (founded) printf("Row: %zu Col: %zu\n", i + 1, j + size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For rows works fine. But if I write numbers in column I always get Row: 1, Col: 18.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the language. The problem you face is you need to come out with the algorithm first.

Actually this can be easily done by just looking at the first number of the 1D array. In your example it is 6 from (6,3,3,2).

1. Look for 6 in your 2D array.
2. Once 6 is found use a loop which loop 4 times (because there are 4 numbers to look for - (6,3,3,2).
3. In the loop, check whether the subsequent numbers are 3,3,2.
4. If it is, return the location
5. Else continue the process to look for 6.
6. Done!

It will look like this:

```
for(x=0; x<rows; x++)
    for(y=0; y<cols; y++)
    {
        if(matrix[x][y] == array1D[0])
            for(z=1; z<array1DSize; z++){
                if(matrix[x][y] != array1D[z])
                    break;
                location = y;
            }
    }
```

Comment: With this code I get some weird results. Value of location is: 1996647070

Comment: @arozma You need to make sure you declare variable `location` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it with a one dimensional array, you can do it like that in C with multidimensional arrays too!

For instance, say you have a two dimensional array like so:

```
int array[5][5]; // 5x5 array of ints
```

You can actually access it in linear fashion, by doing:

```
(*array)[linear offset]
```

So that means if you want to access the 2nd column of the 2nd row, you can do:

```
(*array)[6]
```

Because the 2nd row starts at index 5, and the second column is at index 1, so you would do (5+1) to get 6. Likewise, the 3rd row would start at index 10, so if you wanted the 2nd column in the third row, you can do (10+1).

Knowing that, you can take your original algorithm and adapt it to access the multidimensional array in a linear fashion. This takes place of the "wrap around" possibility as well.